# How send and get parameter with sys_eval mysql trigger function?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I made a trigger and its working fine,

```
BEGIN

DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd=CONCAT('php /home/gauntl6/public_html/trigger.php');
SET result = sys_eval(cmd);
END
```

its working fine and excuting script trigger.php but i want to send the inserted ID/argument in the script so how can i.

Can any one know this how to do send the parameter in sys_eval and to get parameter in trigger.php ??

Comment: I haven't experience with PHP, but according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php): `php /home/gauntl6/public_html/trigger.php arg1 arg2 arg3` should work.

Comment: Thanks, but how do we get arg1 on trigger.php file ?

Comment: Thanks @ wchiquito, but i am stuck with issue i have to send the edited row and inserted row id and would we get this is same way like argv[1] ??

Answer (score 0):

to send argument you should use ',' as a separator for each argument you want to pass to the script do as following:

```
SET cmd=CONCAT('php /home/gauntl6/public_html/trigger.php',argument1,argument2);
```